# Call to a member function diffForHumans() on null only in "updated_at"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

In my `User` model I have `created_at` and `updated_at` columns. When I cast the `created_at` successful but when I cast the `updated_at` it returns an error below:

```
protected $appends = ['created_at_formatted', 'updated_at_formatted'];

public function getCreatedAtFormattedAttribute()
{
    return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
}

public function getUpdatedAtFormattedAttribute()
{
    return $this->updated_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

Tried it to display it `return $user;` it works and displays both. **But when it reaches to the** `view` **it returning an error** *(my view is blank page)*:

> Method App\User::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function diffForHumans() on null

Code in my controller:

```
public function show(\App\User $user)
{
    $messages = auth()->user()->messages_to($user);

    return $user; //if I uncomment this line it works and displays all the formatted dates BUT when I comment, it returning an error above

    return view('messages.show', compact(['user', 'messages']));
}
```

Comment: the `updated_at` is not null. Its just when it goes in the view it returning the error. Idk whats happening.

Comment: unknown issue, but you could do this to prevent that, in your updatedAttribute  return $this->updated_at->diffForHumans() ?? '';

Comment: @Qonvex620 yes Sir. I can do that in my view but in appends it returns an error. I'm appending because of my `vue`.

Comment: not in your view but in your model itself where you are getting your updateAttribute

Comment: @Qonvex620 the model and appends is actually working. The problem Sir when it goes to the view it fails and returns error. But when I uncomment the line above `return $user` it works and returned both formatted dates. But I can `$user->updated->diffForHumans()` in view manually but I'm using `vue` I need a formatted dates.

Comment: Like what I've said, unkown issue, the only way to solve that is to prevent the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems, the `$appends` includes `created_at_formatted`, 'updated_at_formatted`,

you need to change the accessor to `getCreatedAtFormattedAttribute()`,
so you can get `->created_at_formatted`.

`diffForHumans` is the method of Carbon

> By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at and updated_at columns to instances of Carbon, which provides an assortment of helpful methods, and extends the native PHP DateTime class.

However, your value of `updated_at` is nullable, so it is not converted to Carbon, so you cannot use `diffForHuman`, try it like this:

```php
protected $appends = ['created_at_formatted', 'updated_at_formatted'];

public function getCreatedAtFormattedAttribute()
{
    if ($this->created_at) {
        return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

public function getUpdatedAtFormattedAttribute()
{
    if ($this->updated_at) {
        return $this->updated_at->diffForHumans();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, its working. But I'm confused, can you identify what really is the problem why its actually working in `created_at` to just simply `$this->created_at->diffForHumans()` **but in** `updated_at` **it fails** using same coding `$this->updated_at->diffForHumans()`. Does it mean that only `created_at` is casted as `datetime`?

Comment: @gecko what is `$this->created_at` return, if you don't change the code?

Comment: @gecko and I found the accessor method name is wrong, use `getCreatedAtAttribute` will cover the `created_at` attribute, I found the `appends` is `created_at_formatted`, so u need to change your method name to `getCreatedAtFormattedAttribute`. and the `updated_at_formatted` is the same.

Comment: a typo Sir already edited. Thats actually okay. only problem is the  function `getUpdatedAtFormattedAttribute()` but the `getCreatedAtFormattedAttribute` is working.

Comment: I will accept your answer Sir as it solves my problem but still leaving me a question why `$this->created_at->diffForHumans()` is working but `$this->updated_at->diffForHumans()` not.

Comment: @gecko ok, I see, because Eloquent will convert the created_at and updated_at columns to instances of Carbon, so you can use it directly, however, nullable value is not Carbon, so you cannot use method `diffForHumans()`

Comment: @gecko what is updated_at return, or what the value it is?

Comment: same as `created_at` I determined it. I'm using syqlog, and using tinker.

Comment: @gecko is this field's type timestamp? if you are using laravel default timestamp fields. after create the record, the `updated_at` is still nullable, `updated_at` only touch when you update the record,

Comment: in my migration `$table->timestamps();`

Comment: @gecko Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206757/discussion-between-tsaikoga-and-gecko).